# Why REST Service running on Ubuntu is not accessible from the internet?

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core, deployment

I created a simple REST Service in ASP.NET Core and ran it on Ubuntu:
dotnet SimpleSvc.dll

It was running on the port 5000. Then I tried to access it from the internet and I got 404 error.
I have open ports, I also tried to run it as dotnet SimpleSvc.dll --url:0.0.0.0:5000
and it also did not help.
The server where I run it is a VPS. If it was an AWS EC2 then I'd try to use it's internal IP address but here I did not find such the address and localhost does not work neither.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you are saying it worked locally when deployed it on UBUNTU ..but failed on VPS ?

Comment: can you ping the IP of where the app is hosted from elsewhere..